How can I ensure a domain name isn't already taken before creating Azure B2C tenant?
I'm in the process of setting up Azure AD B2C tenants, but I
keep encountering a roadblock. Whenever I try to use a specific domain
name, it tells me it's "Already in use by another directory." However,
I'm uncertain if that's accurate. Is there a way to check if a domain
name is available before I proceed to create a B2C tenant?
I need to create multiple directories, so it's crucial for me to
confirm that the domain name I intend to use is available before
initiating the setup process. Can someone guide me on how to check if a domain name is free for Azure AD B2C before I
attempt to create a tenant?

To check whether the B2C domain name is available or not, you can make use of this Azure Management API call.
Initially, I generated access token to call Azure Management API by running below CLI command:
az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.azure.com --query accessToken --output tsv

Response:

Now, I used that token to call Management API and got below response when domain name is not available:
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/checkNameAvailability?api-version=2021-04-01

{
  "name": "srib2c.onmicrosoft.com",
  "countryCode": "US"
}

Response:

You will get below response when Azure AD B2C domain name is available:
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/checkNameAvailability?api-version=2021-04-01

{
  "name": "sridemob2c.onmicrosoft.com",
  "countryCode": "US"
}

Response:


This is what I exactly looking for! Thank you so much, you spared me a great deal of effort.

Done @NaveenSharma. Yet, I have another additional request for Sirdevi it would be immensely helpful if you could share .NET code for acquiring token and making API call via HTTP.

@PiotrNowak Please post a new question with more details regarding your new requirement and share the link here.

@Sirdevi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78561555/how-to-acquire-azure-management-token-and-call-http-in-net-for-azure-b2c-domain

@PiotrNowak I added answer in that new question with .NET code, please check and let me know if it works : )
